# Running Mocha tests with timeout never finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I'm having difficulties while executing test script on my `node.js` project using Mocha.
Problem is that test script never finishes, unless I finish it manually (ctrl+c). This problem started after I added `--timeout` parameter to `mocha.opts`. Timeout is added because I use `mock-mongoose` library, where suggested timeout is `120000 ms`.
Here is my `mocha.opts`:

```
--require ts-node/register
--watch-extensions ts
--timeout 120000
tests/**/*.ts
```

Here's code example:

```
    it("POST '/route' should return OK", async () => {
        const result = await routeController.createSomething(data)
        expect(result.statusCode).is.equal(HttpStatus.OK)
    })
```

I also tried calling `done()` function, but still not helping.
My project structure:

```
node_modules
src
--- source code...
tests
--- tests source...
package.json
package-lock.json
....
```

Test script: `mocha --opts ./tests/mocha.opts`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `--exit` param which will allow mocha to kill itself.

But the problem here is that you missed to cleanup something in your code.
Read here https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit

You can also try https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running to pinpoint the reason why your code does not terminate.